# Change role on theme my login

Tags: wordpress

I have a little problem with my wordpress and plugin "Theme my login".
I want when someone register on my website chose if he's "particular" or "professional" that will change his role to particular or professional, but when i try it all time it's the default role or role "none"...

```
$user_pass = apply_filters( 'tml_user_registration_pass', wp_generate_password( 12, false ) );
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $sanitized_user_login, $user_pass, $user_email );
    $user_id_role = new WP_User($user_id);
    $user_id_role->set_role('$_POST['new_user_role']');
```

when i do a echo of $new_user_role it displays me the right role.

Thank you if you can help me !
(Sorry for my bad english)